# How can I pass an argument using ajax to an entity reference view?

Tags: views, forms, taxonomy-terms, ajax, entities

I have a Vocabulary called **Program** which has terms nested as follows:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
- Parent 2

  - Child 3
  - Child 4

I would like to create two **Entity Reference** fields using this Vocabulary.  One that displays a select list of **parent terms**.  Then, depending on the parent term that is selected, I would like to populate the second field with it's respective **child terms**.

In the field settings I am using Views as the **Entity Selection** mode on both fields.  I have a view with two **Entity Reference** displays, one for the parent and one for the child.  The child display has a c**ontextual filter** of Parent Taxonomy Term.  However, I'm not sure how to pass the argument using **AJAX** after the Parent term is selected.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be to make your 'child' view an attachment of your parent view. Then select the 'Share exposed filter' option.

Comment: Same thing you can do using SHS module .

Comment: I was able to get it working using the Hierarchical Select module which now integrates with Entity Reference.